# Setting the shown value of a Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

Ok, so I asked this before but it was unclear I guess. I want to take a spinner filled with Strings, and change the selected item within my code, without any user interaction.

The reason for this is that my application will read in some data from another device, and then display that data for the user.

I am using spinners instead of textviews because the user has the option to select something in that spinner, and then press send, to send THAT information back to the other device.

So in the pictures below...the spinner begins on `Sensitive`. I would like to change it to `Insensitive`. But I want to do this in my CODE, so that it ends up looking like the third picture.

[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT

```
int pumpTimeResult = RelayAPIModel.NativeCalls.GetParmJava( RelayAPIModel.PARM_PUMPTIME );
Log.i( "Anti-Pump", "pumpTimeResult ==" + Integer.toString( pumpTimeResult ) );
Spinner pumpTimeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.pumpTimeSpinner );
if( pumpTimeResult != -1 ) {
    int index = pumpTime.indexOf( Integer.toString( pumpTimeResult ) );
     Log.i( "Anti-Pump", "pumpTime index == " + index );
    pumpTimeSpinner.setSelection( index + 5 );
} else {
    pumpTimeSpinner.setSelection( 0 );
}

08-16 14:24:31.151: I/Anti-Pump(3037): pumpCountResult==8
08-16 14:24:31.151: I/Anti-Pump(3037): pumpTimeResult ==34
08-16 14:24:31.151: I/Anti-Pump(3037): pumpTime index == 5
08-16 14:24:31.151: I/Anti-Pump(3037): ppumpDelayResultt==19
```

The spinner has values from 30-300, with "N/A" before it. So there are 271 entries.

Comment: Can't you retrieve all the info you need first, then create the String array, and then use it to populate the spinner, leaving the option you want visible on the first position?

Comment: Find it in the list and set the correct Position?

Comment: @DanielS Yes I could, but I need to do this for like 50 spinners, and a lot of them are numerical values. I would like to keep them in order.

Comment: @Doomsknight If I understand you, then that's what I'm asking how to do, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

`yourSpinner.setSelection(2);`

in your code?

Comment: I gave it a shot, but its not working. I tried it on a bigger list, with entries from 30-300. I tried `setSelection( index )` and `setSelection( index + 5 )`. I am going to update my question with some code.

Comment: `index` is coming out as the number I want it to be, but when I call setSelection it does not work. It sets it to the incorrect value.